# Путь к файлу в  background-image: url

Tags: css

У меня не хочет грузиться фоновая картинка. В инете есть несколько вариантов:

```
BODY {
background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
background-color: #c7b39b;
}
```

И второй вариант:

```
p {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    background-image: url('/img/pushkin.gif');
 }
```

Я испробовал два - не работают. Если фоновый рисунок находится в одной папке с `style.css` и написав `background-image: url(pushkin.gif);` - все работает.

Может, дело в каталогах?

```
/lib/

    /css/

    /img/
```

P.S. файл `*.css` подключен, все работает кроме графики.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да, дело в каталогах, файл ищет от текущего каталога, чтобы подняться на уровень выше, нужно написать две точки: `../`.
Например:

```
p {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 background-image: url('../img/pushkin.gif');
}
```

Путь означает что нужно подняться в родительский каталог, зайти в папку `img` и найти файл `pushkin.gif`.

Comment: Не работает. Ставил одну точку, две и три - по нулям...(((

Comment: Извиняюсь - работает. Забыл lib убрать... Суппер... Большое спасибо

Comment: А если надо на два каталога подняться?

Comment: супер?О_о перенесите html файл и этот стиль уже не будет работать, если вам это неважно то тогда конечно - вперед, но лично я всегда все url'ы (как в css так и вообще где угодно) прописываю от корня чтобы рассположение html страницы никаким образом не влияло на работу css..<br>Ну да не суть, на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные...

Comment: Если нужно на два каталога, тогда "../../"

Comment: *Никогда* не указывайте относительные пути, кроме случаев, когда этот путь неизвестен. url('/lib/img/pushkin.gif').

Comment: Я пытался от корня прописать. Не получилось. Сейчас я на локалке тестирую, там корень один, на хосте другой будет. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В html файле у меня прописан полный путь в css:

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/mystyle.css" tppabs="http://www.myhost.com/lib/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css">

а вот как прописать полный путь в css файле?

   < Никогда не указывайте относительные пути, кроме случаев, когда этот путь неизвестен. url('/lib/img/pushkin.gif'). >

Так почему то не работатет...

Comment: Если есть где посмотреть, дайте ссылку. Имхо у вас там бардак какой-то либо файла нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если структура каталогов такая как вы указали, то нужно писать путь к картинке относительно расположения файла css, что в данном случае вот так:

```
background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
```

И всегда, ВСЕГДА, когда задаете какой-то фон картинкой, нужно указывать размеры изображения. (т.е. width и height)

Comment: Можно поинтерисоватся - зачем?О_о

Comment: А вы попробуйте не задать и сами увидите эту порнографию ;)  
Хотя в случае с body картинка будет, но абы как. Вообще картинки на фон ставятся зачастую в пустые блоки и если не указать размеры - блока не будет видно.

Comment: Согласен - это лишнее задавать размеры.

Comment: У меня стоит background-repeat : repeat-x;
Иногда задаю команды отцентрировать. Картинка то имеет размеры - вот она и ставится в свои размеры например в центр...

Answer (score 1):

Для установки фоновой картинки:

```
body {
    background:url('./img/bg.jpg');
    background-color: #c7b39b;
}
```

Не `background-image`, а просто `background:url`.

Comment: Не background-image,а просто background:url.<br>
ЛОЛ а разница? xD

Comment: Заменил на background:url (ради интереса) - не работает

Comment: Мой вариант рабочий 100%, если вы не смогли понять, как его правильно применить, то извините :) А фоновую картинку можно и так, и так задавать...

Comment: background:url - универсальный,и работает везде.Не спорю разницы,почти нет,но хочу заметить этот код тоже работает.

Comment: Надо написать background:url(/lib/img/img.gif);
или           background:url('/lib/img/img.gif');
Хотя испробовал оба варианта - не работатет. Печально.(((

Comment: точку перед забыли, './libl/img/img.gif'

Comment: но только если эти папки в одном каталоге

Comment: хотя проще было прописать полный путь

Comment: < Если есть где посмотреть, дайте ссылку. Имхо у вас там бардак какой-то либо файла нет. >

Пока все на локалке и файлы все есть. Если прописываю

    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');

работает. А если 

    background-image: url('/lib/img/bg.jpg');

не работатет.

Comment: Скинул на сервак www.fxopen.monstrs-inc.com
проблема была в левой панели. Как должна отображаться панель
www.monstrs-inc.com

Answer (score 0):

если у вас картинки хранятся в /lib/img/ То так и пишите **background:url(/lib/img/img.gif)**
"/" в начале означает корень сайта