# Задать путь к файлу

Tags: html, css

Есть html-файл в корневом меню, таблица стилей к которому находится в папке CSS. Как прописать бекграунд к секции в CSS-файле, если картинка лежит папке IMG (которая, в свою очередь, находится в корневом меню) ?

Comment: возможно дубликат - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35393/Путь-к-файлу-в-background-image-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно прописать вот так: (нужно заменить название картинки на свою).

Для фона страницы:

```
body {background:#fff url(../IMG/1.png); }
```

Для id `#bloc`:

```
#bloc {background:#fff url(../IMG/1.png); }
```

Для класса `.bloc`:

```
.bloc {background:#fff url(../IMG/1.png); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
  background-image: url(../img/filename.jpg);
}
```