# background-image: url не видит папку с картинками

Tags: css, css3

`background-image: url("../images/2.gif");` не видит картинку пробовал и одинарными камычками и имя папки менял и имя картинки и расширение картинки. не видит папку. если в корень положить картинку все работает а вот в каталоге не работает. Что я делаю не так? Такой вопрос поднимался не однократно но вроде никто толку так и не добился.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Путь к файлу в  background-image: url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35393/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d0%b2-background-image-url)

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский вот как раз при такой конструкции и не работает

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский просто открываю как файл

Comment: вот HTML https://pastebin.com/vxgH3kvA вот CSS https://pastebin.com/n2MVXeyu так работает, но почему именно только так? Правельнее же с `../images/`

Comment: Нашёл [хорошую статью об путях](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/), думаю поможет осмыслить это всё

Comment: Такое поведение может быть из-за перемешения файлов по директориям, так пишут на англоязычных ресурсах. Используй `/images/1.png` без `..`

Comment: @L.F.C.Спасибо глянул, но там к html файлам относится, как показала практика к обычным файлам это не применимо. Хотя вроде раньше так делал все работало. Не знаю почему сейчас не работает.

Comment: @L.F.C.Статья хорошая но так как там написано не работает)

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский все дело может быть в том что я использую `reset.css` потому у меня не работает с точками.

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Спасибо!